# GestureDetector in Flutter: how to detect long press into vertical drag?

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector

I have a question about the `GestureDetector` widget in Flutter. I have the following situation: I have two buttons. I want to do something when the first button is long pressed. Then I want to do something when the user drags vertically over the second button still in press from the first button.

How can I do this with the `GestureDetector` widget in Flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a draggable class on flutter that will serve better your purpose check this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html

Comment: Ok thank you for your response can you give me an example how I could do that with two buttons.